# Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.UnionSubclassEntityPersister when using Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, mapping, entity

I get the following error when launching my Spring Boot App. I assume it has something to do with my Relationships from one class to both of my child classes(`Employee`, `ClientUser`) of a common subclass(`MyUser`).

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at app.Application.main(Application.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.UnionSubclassEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.getSuperCollection(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.addPropertyPath(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2347) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3906) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.UnionSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(UnionSubclassEntityPersister.java:213) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
... 28 common frames omitted
```

These are the entity classes.
mapped superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdentifiableEntity {
@Id
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue
@Column
private UUID id;

public IdentifiableEntity() {
}

public IdentifiableEntity(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

parent class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class MyUser extends IdentifiableEntity {
@Column
private String name;
@Column
private String email;
@Column
private String phoneNumber;
@Column
private String password;
@Column
private Role role;

public MyUser() {
}
//getters and setters omitted
}
```

first child

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends MyUser {
@Column
private String address;
@Column
private String image;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
private List<Appointment> appointments;

public Employee() {
}
//getters and setters omitted
}
```

second child

```
@Entity
public class ClientUser extends MyUser {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientUser")
private List<Appointment> appointments;

public ClientUser() {
}
//getters and setters omitted
}
```

both are referenced in another table

```
@Entity
public class Appointment extends IdentifiableEntity {

@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;

@ManyToOne
private ClientUser clientUser;

public Appointment() {
}

//getters and setters omitted
}
```

Comment: You should declare strategy field from @GeneratedValue

Comment: Possibly a bug in hibernate 5.2.14 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12332. Perhaps could try upgrading to 5.2.15

Comment: @RistoPärnapuu that fixed it. I ended up upgrading to 5.2.17 right away, but the error is gone. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly caused by a bug in hibernate 5.2.14: hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12332. Upgrading to 5.2.15 or to the latest version should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had an @version annotation at a certain (same named) column in an automatically generated POJO class. After I had removed it, the error had gone.

e: similar to the solution of Ali, but for me it was not the datatype itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out that there was a problem in my entity classes. I had used `BigInteger` for versioning.

```
@Version
private BigInteger version
```

I changed to `Integer` and problem was solved.